# How can I display map full screen and centered with react-simple-maps

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-simple-maps

I am facing this issue when I want to display Mexico map[image]
As you can see is not showing completely, I dont want to be able to zoom in, I just want the map to be shown centered and complete

this is my code so far.

```
const geoUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/diegovalle/5129746/raw/c1c35e439b1d5e688bca20b79f0e53a1fc12bf9e/mx_tj.json'
//const geoUrl = mapa2 ;
return (
<div>
<h1>Bienvenido a Blog!</h1>
<ComposableMap style={{backgroundColor:'gray'}} projection={'geoAlbers'}>
      <Geographies style={{backgroundColor:'green', bottom:100}} geography={geoUrl}>
        {({ geographies }) =>
          geographies.map(geo => (
            <Geography key={geo.rsmKey} geography={geo} />
          ))
        }
      </Geographies>
  </ComposableMap>
```

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with unrelated tags (in this case [tag:google-maps]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the map you could use `projectionConfig` props with `center`. Something like:

```
<ComposableMap
      style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}
      projection="geoAlbers"
      projectionConfig={{
        center:[-5, 25]
      }}
 >
```

The result is:

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-annotation-forked-o4mrv?file=/src/MapChart.js) a codesandbox of your code modified.

Comment: wow! thanks a lot that solved my problem!

Comment: @josesantosalvarezmacias no problem. Happy coding =)